# angularjs - filtering a json api with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an api that I am calling like so:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/people',
  headers: {
    'Accept' : "application/json; charset=utf-8"  
},
}).then(function successCallback(data) {
     $scope.camps = data.data;
  }, function errorCallback(data) {
        console.log(data);
   });
});
```

and I am doing an `ng-repeat` with a directive inside to loop through the data and output the variables:

```
<div ng-repeat="camp in camps track by $index | filter:search:strict">
     <tile></tile>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to filter the `<tile>`, so I have an `input` that looks like this:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Person name</label>
    <input ng-model="search.name">
</md-input-container>
```

Inside the `tile` directive I have a portion that looks like this:

```
<div class="variation-text col-md-8">
    <h3 class="problem-header grey-header">{{ camp.name }}</h3>
 </div>
```

and this is outputting the `name` endpoint from the api. How can I filter this `name` endpoint using the `input` field shown above?

When I currently run this application I get an error from Angular stating: `Error: filter:notarray Not an array` ([url](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray?p0=0))..

What am I doing wrong for this to not work? I'd love some help. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `data.data` when log it to console?

Comment: @DataHerder It returns a json object. Image: https://i.gyazo.com/68a284843d059f87eb830aae5583cc6b.png

Comment: Error is clearly telling you that the data is not an array. . Show sample of data

Comment: @charlietfl This is what data.data returns. [image](https://i.gyazo.com/ee5933284ab2dd0d492ba37330bda52d.png)

Comment: Copy sample of actual json either from response body of request or just open the url itself. Seems right in picture

Comment: @charlietfl here is an example of the response body: `[{"id":1,"name":"T2 Nav Test","kind":"multiple_page_ab","goal"...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is order of operations in `ng-repeat` query

From [ngRepeat Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> Note: track by must always be the last expression:

What is happening is the filter is being applied to `$index` which isn't an array and thus you get the `notarray` error

Change to

```
<div ng-repeat="camp in camps | filter:search:strict  track by $index">
```

Comment: Thank you, this removed the error, however, I'm still unable to sort using the `input` from above...

Comment: what is `strict` ..is it a variable in scope? If not needs to be boolean

Comment: I was using `strict` because the angular docs were using `strict` to filter. [filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)